# laravel is not reading the code(insert validated data) after returning the JSON response to ajax call

Tags: javascript, ajax, insert, laravel-8, model-validation

```php
$user=new User;
$validator=Validator::make($request->all(),$user->rules,$customMessage);

if($validator->fails())
{
    return response()->json(['error'=>$validator->errors()]);
}

else
{
    return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records']);
    User::create($request->all());
    return redirect('/show');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

statement below `return` will not execute, it is already dead code

```
return response()->json(['success'=>'Added new records']);

//below statement will not execute
User::create($request->all()); // dead code
return redirect('/show'); //dead code
```

Comment: How i can overcome and execute the code to insert data & redirect to the page with URL('/show')

Comment: for this normally i use
`$request->session()->flash('success', 'Added new records');`
instead of return json